# CSS min height not working

Tags: css

I have a large `div` that I want to put content in. I want the `div` to be padded and have a minimum height so that if there is too much text in the `div` it expands down to maintain the padding. But I also don't want it to get less than 100px in height. Currently, when I run this code, some of the text falls outside of the `div`.

HTML:

```
<div id='content'>
    <div>lots of text in here</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    min-height: 100px;
    width: 800px;
    padding: 60px;
}
```

Comment: You’re wrapping two <div>s. I think your markup should be:

<div id='content'>
          <p>lots of text in here</p>
       </div>

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle example, because your code seems to work fine for me.

Comment: I juts tried this code in Google Chrome and I cannot replicate your issue. This is my markup.


 <html>
 <head>

 <style type="text/css">
 #content{
      position: relative;
      margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid gray;
     min-height: 100px;
     width: 800px;
    padding: 60px;
     }
 </style>

 </head>

 <body>

 <div id='content'>
     <div>lots of text in here</div>
 </div>

 </body>
 </html>

Comment: the first comment solved the problem. thanks

Comment: this sounds like a browser specific issue, are you testing it in IE?

Comment: @Fitoschido: Go ahead and post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, try to use paragraphs in your HTML, instead of duplicating divs. It does not work because the duplicate div is not styled in your CSS.

```
<div id='content'>
    <p>lots of text in here</p>
</div>
```

If this solves your problem, feel free to accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `height:auto;` to your css, it may help.